# How to Hide Dialog Tile using CSS in Script Editor webpart in SharePoint On premises

Tags: css, script, dialog

I am using SharePoint 2013  on premises  environment.  I am opening a page (Pages library) in a popup. I  want to hide the dialog title using S**cript editor web part**,  and achieved the requirement  below script

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
         window.parent.$(".ms-dlgTitleText").remove();         
    });
</script>
```

But i want the same implementation using CSS styles. I tried the below one but not working

```
<style type="text/css">
  .ms-dlgTitleText
  {
     display:none!important;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: Where you are keeping this css code? On which page?

Comment: how are you calling the modal popup ? can share that code ?

Comment: <a class="link-view-more" href="javascript:void(0)" data-site="http://sprootsite/sites/SPDev2016/Pages/SingleSitePermissions.aspx?SiteUrl=http://sprootsite/sites/HR">View More</a>

Answer (score 3):

```
<style type="text/css">
#dialogTitleSpan {
display:none;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

I have followed the following steps:

- Edited the Page listing page
- Kept Content Editor WebPart
- Inserted following code

  `<style type="text/css">
    .ms-dlgTitleText
    {
       display:none!important;
    }
  </style>`
- Save the page.

And it hides the title of page. See snap.

[image]